# AlarmManager Calling Function in Same Class

Tags: android, timer, location, alarmmanager, google-play-services

I am trying to give a LocationClient a two-minute period to connect before calling getLastLocation on it. Initially I implemented this with a Timer (and TimerTask), but because Timers do not work in sleepmode, I would like to translate it to an AlarmManager. However, I am a bit confused as to how to do this, considering an AlarmManager calls another class, whereas I want to remain in the same class and simply delay for a two-minute period.

This is how it looks with a Timer.

```
 Timer theTimer = new Timer();
    theTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(checkIfGooglePlay() && checkTime()) {
                getPostLocation();
                stopSelf();
                mLocationClient.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }, TWO_MINUTES);
```

Comment: AlarmManager Can call the same class using pendingIntent

Comment: So I could call mLocationClient.connect(), and then create a PendingIntent with an AlarmManager set for two minutes later on that class?

Comment: I don't know your proper requirement, but up-to what extent I have understood, you should use a Service class to accomplish this. Which can be waked up using AlarmManager Class or in a normal way, use an interface to communicate with the Service from your Activity...

Answer (score 1):

Alarm Manager calls a broadcast receiver via a pending intent.  Just make that BroadcastReceiver implementation a private subclass of the class that registers it.  That way it has full access to class member variables and functions.

Comment: Hi @Gabe, I apologize for this noobish follow-up question, but I am not aware of (and believe it is not allowed), to extend two classes. What you are recommending, if I am not mistaken, is that I write a new subclass that extends two classes: public class TheSubClass extends TheFirstClass, BroadcastReceiver

Comment: No, I'm talking about an inner class.  A class can contain a second class inside of it.

Comment: Hi @Gabe, I am still having a bit of difficulty having the receiver/service being called. I have created a new question to address this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429961/service-calling-alarmmanager-on-another-service. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using Java's `Thread.sleep()`. It's a static method so you don't need to instantiate a new `Thread`. It throws a `InterruptedException`, which, in simpler cases, shouldn't bother you.

From http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html:

> > Causes the thread which sent this message to sleep for the given interval of time (given in milliseconds and nanoseconds).

Comment: This is a horrible idea.  If its on the UI thread, it will block the thread and cause the UI to become unresponsive, probably setting off the watchdog timer.  If its on another thread it will prevent the thread from doing its job.  Sleep is 99% of the time a sign of a programmer who doesn't know what he's doing.